# Picking data from all csv files placed at a location

Tags: r

I have several csv files at a common location. Each csv file has the same column names but different data. The names of these csv files are different. Can I write a code in R to read in the data from all the csv files and then put it in a single data frame? The names of the csv files keep differing so I wish to have a code such that I do not have to explicitly specify the names of the csv files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `list.files` for listing all files at a location, `read.csv` for loading one file into R, and `rbind` to put them into a single data.frame.

The code could look like this (untested)

```
setwd(location)
fnames <- list.files()
csv <- lapply(fnames, read.csv)
result <- do.call(rbind, csv)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv") # reads only .csv files in a folder
allcsv.files <- list()  
count <- 1
for (file in filelist) {
  dat <- read.csv(file) 
  allcsv.files[[count]] <- dat 
  count <- count + 1
}
allfiles <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, allcsv.files)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    setwd("common location")
    f <- list.files()
    d <- data.frame()
    for(i in 1:length(f)){
       file <- read.csv(f[i],stringsasFactors=F)
       d <- rbind(d,file)
    }
    colnames(d) <- c("col1","col2")
    write.csv(d,"combined.csv",row.names=F)
```